# Configure OpenVPN client to continue trying after authorization fails

Tags: openvpn

I just managed to cut my OpenVPN connection to some 20 servers tonight.  I was experimenting with the `client-connect` scripts, and at some point one of the scripts returned a non zero response.  This non zero response triggered an `AUTH: Received AUTH_FAILED control message` in the `syslog` which eventually resulted in a `SIGTERM[soft,auth-failure] received, process exiting` exit from the OpenVPN client.  Is there a way to protect myself from this?  Any configuration on the server or client side?

Comment: Any help is appreciated... anyone?

Comment: This is like typing something in google and getting 0 pages found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to protect yourself from this is to wrap the openvpn client in a while loop that restarts it.  Looking at the openvpn discussion list it appears this was a design decision made because auth failures likely require manual intervention and having the client retry repeatedly would in many cases lock out the user (according to SOX/PCI compatible security precautions).  It isn't clear what your OS config is, in OS X the launchd would take care of respawning this.

Comment: Will do this and see how it works.  I'm thinking this as a protection mechanism against misconfigurations on my side that would result in a disconnected openvpn client.  As for the clientes they are linux so I'll cron my way through it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been seeing the same problem intermittently. polynomial's answer seems to be correct - I'm sure in my cause it's a network/connection error and not authentication.

Starting OpenVPN with the following script has fixed it for me, although you might need to adjust it for your local setup:

```
#!/bin/bash

maxAttempts=10
waitTime=5
device=tap0

attempts=1
while true; do
    /etc/init.d/openvpn restart
    sleep $waitTime

    vpnIp=$( ip addr show dev $device | grep 'inet ' | cut -d ' ' -f 6 | cut -d '/' -f 1 )

    if [ ! -x $vpnIp ]; then
        break
    fi

    attempts=$((attempts+1))
    if [ $attempts -gt $maxAttempts ]; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. You should probably edit to: "/etc/init.d/openvpn restart $device"  or whatever the tunnel '*.conf' name is, so it will only restart this specific openvpn client/tunnel.. Otherwise it would also restart a running openvpn server - if present.

Comment: Great idea, although I suspect the init scripts are specific to each Linux distribution. On Debian Wheezy `/etc/init.d/openvpn restart tap0` gives `failure: No such VPN is running: tap0`. I can't find any reference to the device in the script. Which version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I'm also running Debian Wheezy (7.6), in my case "/etc/init.d/openvpn restart tun1" works. For this to work the file has to be named /etc/openvpn/<interface>.conf, in my case /etc/openvpn/tun1.conf.

Comment: Ah I see, so it's really a config name rather than a device name; just that the config name is named after the device?